# unable to debug errai-cdi quickstart

Tags: eclipse, maven, errai

I have use a Maven archetype for installed errai-cdi quickstart project in Eclipse. But when i run the goal "gwt:debug"  the "Gwt developpement Mode" user interface is not launch,  the goal execution is blocked at this line written in the console:"[INFO] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000". When i cancel the debugging and re-launch it , i have this error: "[ERROR] ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use" to solve this error, i must close Eclipse.

I don't know if it's a bug or if i have missing something
Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should launch the application with `mvn gwt:run`.

When you launch with `mvn gwt:debug`, the Dev Mode process waits for you to connect a Java debugger before it finishes launching. If and when you want to do this, check out [this tutorial](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html) which has screenshots and step-by-step instructions for attaching Eclipse as a remote debugger.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you would be so kind as to accept this as the correct answer, I'd appreciate it. :)

Comment: sorry, i think i don't have the right to mark a correct answer, because i don't see how to do it.